# Could't get "href" in other pages

Tags: html, selenium

I couldn't get other "href" in other pages,but I still could get "href" in first page.
What's wrong with it? Could I get  total "href" in all pages if I change Xpath ?

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
# https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/store/%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8FWatsons:watsons  (original page)
url = "https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product?p=%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8F&pg=2"
browser.get(url)


# 商品連結

# 如何取得正確的Xpath ?
linkPath = "//section[contains(@class,'MainListing__StoreBoothWrap')]/div/div/div/ul/li/a"
product_links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(linkPath)
print(len(product_links))

for link in product_links:
   print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: What is expected output? Which links are you trying to extract.

Comment: My expected output is the product links(src-0 to src-59) in all pages. I try the first page(which url = https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/store/%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8FWatsons:watsons),It works. However, when I try to get the other product links in other pages, I get none.

Comment: So, I just think what's wrong with the url ( other pages ) or the Xpath ? Should I change the url or Xpath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below locators to extract the product link.

Xpath:

```
//ul[@class='gridList']/li/a
```

CSS - selector:

```
ul.gridList > li > a
```

**The Code:**

```
# Imports Required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

for i in range(1,5): # Iterate from page 1 to 4
    driver.get("https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product?p=%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8F&pg={}".format(i))
    
    # Wait Until the product appear
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='gridList']")))

    # Get the products
    product_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='gridList']/li/a")

    # Iterate over 'product_links' to get all the 'href' values
    for j,link in zip(range(len(product_links)),product_links):
        print(f"{j} : {link.get_attribute('href')}")
```

Comment: I got it ! Thank you so much. I see that if I use right Xpath, I will get the exact elements.